# Impact of setting BasicDataSource.maxActive to -1

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbcp, struts-config

As the description of the property maxAcive of  `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`
says that it sets the maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time, or ***negative for no limit***.

> Will there be any impact in the application if we set the maxActive
>   value to -1?

Any clarification for this would be highly appreciable.

Thanks
Marshal

Answer (score 0):

There are no negative impact(if that is what you meant by your question) per se in the application. It would override the default value of 8